# How to get exact date difference in days in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get the difference between the two dates in a number of days in `PostgreSQL`. But I'm getting the exact value as expected.

For Example, Time at UTC now is `2021-12-30 10:50:00`.

If I take a timestamp of more than one day. Let's say, `2021-12-29 09:00:00`
which is more than 24hrs from now.

So, If I do select `(NOW()::DATE - '2021-12-29 09:00:00'::DATE)<=1;` It should give me `false`. But it's giving me `true`; But the date difference is more than 24hrs doesn't that make it 2 days? What am I missing?.
I also tried : `DATE_PART('day', NOW()::timestamp - DATE_OF_RECORDING::timestamp)` but same result.

Comment: `::DATE` means you skip the TIME part of the timestamps. I.e. you're doing '2021-12-30' - '2021-12-29', which is 1 day.

Comment: But I tried the timestamp also. As mentioned above. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(NOW() - timestamp '2021-12-29 09:00:00') < interval'1' day
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=835db28ba753587f5ab552d7537ba3e3